# How can i share only one my all private git repository to 50 or 60 clients . Is there any way i can do this without making my repository public

Tags: git, version-control, github, github-for-windows

How can i share only one of my all private git repository to 50 or 60 clients . Is there any way i can do this without making my repository public

Answer (score 1):

1. Serve your Git repository over HTTP.  Use SSL + HTTP authentication.  This is configured at the web server level ([Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)/[Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule)/etc.)
2. Serve your Git repository over SSH.
3. Set up [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).
4. Pay [GitHub](https://github.com/plans) for a private repo.